# Do I need to build out CCK fields before migrate_d2d_ui?

Tags: 7, entities, migrations

Using the migrate_d2d_ui module to migrate Drupal 6 cck content to Drupal 7, I previously asked "Do I need to create CCK content types before migrate_d2d_ui?" and presume the answer is "Yes" based on my personal experience.

This follow-up question is whether it is necessary to also build out all the cck fields for content types containing cck fields.  I am hoping the answer is "No" as this would imply a lot of work.

It would seem that migrate_d2d_ should be smart enough to recognize the D6 cck fields and create the corresponding D7 fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually concluded that the answer to this question is 'yes' and ended up persisting my content structure (content types and field definitions) in features so it could be easily replicated when some errant step in the migration corrupted the database.